# Use @ApplicationException on checked exception to set rollback attribute

Tags: exception, jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb

I know that the EJB 3.1 [`@ApplicationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/ApplicationException.html) can be applied to runtime exceptions to mark them as unchecked application exceptions. But can it also be used on checked exceptions (that are application exceptions by default) in order to configure them as rollback only (i.e. [`rollback=true`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/ApplicationException.html#rollback())) or is it only allowed on runtime exceptions?

(Although it might be a bad design choice to have an application/checked exception that does not allow a client to recover it's transaction from it.)

Comment: In addition to what B'Bek explained, I would like to add that with a runtime exception, the bean instance will likely get destroyed by the container, while by using an `@ApplicationException(rollback=true)` only rollback occurs leaving the bean alive in the pool.

Comment: @leonardo good point sir..

Answer (score 0):

> But can it also be used on checked exceptions (that are application exceptions by default) in order to configure them as rollback only (i.e. `rollback=true`) or is it only allowed on runtime exceptions

Application exceptions dont cause an automatic Container-Managed Rollback , by setting `rollback=true` tell container to rollback transaction before it is passed to the client. this mean both of the following code will be rollback before exception is delivered.

```
//specifies as checked expection
@ApplicationException(rollback=true)
public class ParkingSystemException extends Exception {
ApplicationException

//specifies as system exception as application Exception
@ApplicationException(rollback=true)
public class ParkingSystemException extends RuntimeException {
```